# Latest data last check is above 1h in zabbix server

Tags: mysql, zabbix

I have been adding host machine as the number of host increases the zabbix server is running very slow and the latest data retrived shows last check time above 1h can anyone help me on this

also the zaabix server log say

slow query
[snap of latest data lasttime check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7yXs.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What does that png tell you?

Comment: thank u for responding, I have figure out the problem 
the actual problem was the time to execute the sql query were too slow
after editing the "innodb_buffer_pool_size" it worked like magic